# I fried my Fluke DMM while measuring voltage across a BBQ Piezo spark igniter. How to fix?

Tags: multimeter

I was trying to figure out how I broke my Fluke (and more importantly, how to fix it). I had a grill spark generator (such as pictured below). It wasn't working correctly, so I was measuring (I think) the Voltage across the leads. I had the leads measuring it for a few seconds (at least 15 "sparks"). At some point, the DMM went dead, and it won't turn back on. When I remove and replace the battery, some of the LCD segments flash for a fraction of a second and then go dead. It doesn't do anything useful any longer.

Any ideas where to start with troubleshooting?

[image: https://www.amazon.com/MENSI-Ignition-Electronic-Catering-euqipment/dp/B07BF5652B]

Comment: It's likely damaged beyond easy repair. The spark generator produces instances of thousands of volts, well above the rated inputs on the Fluke.

Comment: I fried my Fluke a few years ago doing something equally as stupid. It was a pity, I liked that meter.

Comment: Bin it, buy another, keep the leads for spares if they are still good.

Comment: Hint, buy several really cheap meters, you can get 10 for the price of a decent one. Then you can calibrate each against the others, adjust the adjustable ones, mark the non-adjustable ones. When (like me) you kill the current range through forgetting to swap the leads around (fuses don't always protect), mark that one as 'voltage only' with a dob of paint. Many jobs can usefully use two or three meters at once. And now, if you kill one, it's nowhere near as painful.

Comment: Don't put voltage across the terminals that is greater than the max rated voltage of the meter. Most flukes are only good for for a thousand or so, piezoelectric generators can produce thousands of volts

Answer (score 4):

The multimeter has a maximum voltage rating of approximately 1000 volts (1 kilovolt).

Piezoelectric spark generators can provide voltage pulses of over 16 kilovolts.

So you killed your multimeter by exceeding the rated voltage limit by about tenfold.

It is not repairable any more.